# How to synchronize the display of two web pages in separate browsers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, synchronization

TLDR: How could I sync the display of two web pages in browsers on separate computers?

**Background:**

I have developed a dashboard using MVC hosted on an IIS server that is used to display info on two large screen displays that are side-by-side. The server provides different layouts for each screen based on the URL. The layouts are created with reasonably pure Bootstrap 3 markup. Each screen is connected to an independent Google TV that loads the screen as the home page. The content is relatively static, so reloading the page every 10 minutes has been fine to this point.

**Problem**

I am considering a horizontally scrolling marquee (i.e. a ticker) at the bottom, but I would need it to span both screens.

**Question**

Is there a way to synchronize the displays reasonably accurately (i.e. better than 1s discrepancy) so that the text can slide from one screen to the other and not look too broken?

*Note: I am primarily interested in methods that can be implemented from the MVC application, not by hacking the Google TVs or the browser, so that it remains broswer/machine agnostic.*

Comment: That's an interesting situation. I would recommend looking into [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc). It uses websockets for realtime two way communication. You could leverage bysending your marquee data to both screens simultaneously and then just have the second screen hold off on displaying the data for however many seconds it takes for text to cross the first screen. This would make it look like the text is scrolling across both screens.

Comment: SignalR is a good fit for your requirement...

Comment: The requirement has been dropped, so I won't be implementing this, however, @sam2929 if you want to add your SignalR suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it. It looks like it would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking into SignalR. It uses web sockets for real-time two-way communication. You could leverage it by sending your marquee data to both screens simultaneously and then just have the second screen hold off on displaying the data for however many seconds it takes for text to cross the first screen. This would make it look like the text is scrolling across both screens.

Microsoft has some good tutorials for using SignalR for real-time communications on their website: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you're using asp.NET, SignalIR might be the de facto solution for your needs (as pointed from user @sam2929). However, if you have direct access to the server, I would suggest you Socket.io (a popular library which makes working with WebSocket plain and easy) combined with [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode), which is the same IIS extension they use on Windows Azure.